# VirtualMode to remove MSDOS filesystem files in Ubuntu?

Tags: filesystem, virtualization, delete, ms-dos

I have a MSDOS memory card where I would like delete files by my Ubuntu installation. 
I run on those files `sudo rm /media/masi/g0399/DCIM/video.mp4` but I get a filesystem error that the filesystem is only readable, although permissions 700 and owner:group is masi:masi. 
It is possible there is some mechanical switch somewhere which is blocking this removal. 
It is possible that in the reader device itself where "block option" which however seems to be only in one mode all the time.

How can you remove files on MSDOS filesystem in Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you just want to format your stick? If so open `files`, right click it on the left and choose `format`, make it FAT32 (still dos but will be blank) for compatibility, if not please update the question based on @Takkat comment

Comment: There is no mechanical switch causing the problem. This is a filesystem problem of unknown origin. I really do not understand it. OSX filesystem problem would be more logical, but MSDOS like fat32 not, and not NTFS.